# How do I check whether a file I'm opening is a block device or charachter device?

Tags: c

Is there a function in c that checks whether a file is a block device or charachter device?

Thanks!

Comment: Filesystems can only be mounted if they are on block devices.

Comment: @Motes Maybe the "file" is a serial interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `lstat`, if you're under linux:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat

You should have access to the macros `S_ISCHR` and `S_ISBLK`.